# Auto crop a rectangle

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, crop

I want to auto crop the image which I took it from tablet camera. Actually I want to take the picture of id cards and need to auto corp it, I am using black background but sometimes it is too glaze and there is a reflection also, at that time its not cropped properly. Can anyone assist me with c# code to crop the images(Note : I am using phone cameras to take the image of id cards, mostly the background will be black and sometime it will be some other things).

Below I mentioned my code also:

```
private void ProcessImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        // lock image
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        // step 1 - turn background to black
        ColorFiltering colorFilter = new ColorFiltering();

        colorFilter.Red = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.Green = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.Blue = new IntRange(0, 64);
        colorFilter.FillOutsideRange = false;

        colorFilter.ApplyInPlace(bitmapData);

        // step 2 - locating objects
        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

        blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
        blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
        blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

        blobCounter.ProcessImage(bitmapData);
        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        // step 3 - check objects' type and highlight
        SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        Pen yellowPen = new Pen(Color.Yellow, 2); // circles
        Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);       // quadrilateral
        Pen brownPen = new Pen(Color.Brown, 2);   // quadrilateral with known sub-type
        Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2);   // known triangle
        Pen bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);     // triangle

        for (int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++)
        {
            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blobs[i]);

            DoublePoint center;
            double radius;


            List<IntPoint> corners;

            // is triangle or quadrilateral
            if (shapeChecker.IsConvexPolygon(edgePoints, out corners))
            {
                // get sub-type
                PolygonSubType subType = shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(corners);


                Pen pen;

                if (subType == PolygonSubType.Rectangle)
                {
                    pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? redPen : bluePen;
                }
                else
                {
                    pen = (corners.Count == 4) ? brownPen : greenPen;
                }

                //g.DrawPolygon( pen, ToPointsArray( corners ) );

                if (pen.Color.Name == "Red")
                {
                    int intdummy = 0;
                    g.DrawRectangle(pen, corners[0].X, corners[0].Y, 1150, 750);

                    //Code for corpping///////
                    pictureBox2.Image = bitmap;
                    pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    Bitmap croppedBitmap = new Bitmap("E:\\xxx\\Vicas Tablet\\WinImager\\cropimage\\cropimage\\Testing Images\\Image1.jpg");

                     //croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(corners[0].X, corners[0].Y,1150,750),System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);

                    croppedBitmap = croppedBitmap.Clone(
                       new Rectangle(corners[0].X, corners[0].Y, ((int)corners[1].X - (int)corners[0].X), ((int)corners[2].Y - (int)corners[1].Y)), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);

                    pictureBox2.Image = croppedBitmap;
                    ////End code for cropping///////////
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tell me what color of your ID Card have?

Comment: Its in different colors because I am trying with multiple type of cards. For all images the background is in black color but now the problem is with reflection from the card. If there is reflection its not corpping properly.

Comment: This looks similar to this StackOverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828712/crop-image-with-multiple-x-and-y-points-c-sharp