# Crop Image with multiple X and Y points c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, image-processing, console-application

I have images that I need to crop and have multiple X,Y co-ordinates to cut out the business card or paper.
What would be the best way to do it.

My Co Ordinates is the following.
X: 490, y: 0
X: 1442, y: 0
X: 1442, y: 4031
X: 490, y: 4031

[image]

Comment: There is nothing built into .NET that will do this for you automatically, your only option is to get a image processing library capable of doing this, or writing the code yourself.

Comment: ...i.e. You're either asking for a recommendation, or the scope of this question is way too broad.

Comment: A recommendation would be helpful. Just trying to find a way of doing this.

Comment: This process is also called deskewing by the way

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the [KeyStoneCommand](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/po/keystonecommand.html) from the [Leadtools Image Processing Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Leadtools.Image.Processing/)

This Nuget package also includes a detect document ip command that you can use if you don't know the bounding box of the business card that will detect and give you back the 4 points of the card.

Here is a code snippet:

```
private RasterImage DetectAndDeskew(RasterImage image)
{
   DetectDocumentCommand detectDocumentCommand = new DetectDocumentCommand();
   detectDocumentCommand.Run(image);

   if (detectDocumentCommand.DocumentArea == null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("No document detected");
      return null;
   }

   KeyStoneCommand command = new KeyStoneCommand(detectDocumentCommand.DocumentArea);
   command.Run(image);

   image = command.TransformedImage;
   return image;
}
```

Here is the output image from this process:

[image: output image from code]

Disclaimer: I am an employed by the maker of this nuget